# Disconnecting Long, Clipped Pipe Runs

Tags: plumbing, pipe, joints

When the installer fitted my floor standing boiler, he neatly, clipped the main 22mm feed to the wall.  The pipe in question enter the room at floor level and has several components (pressure reducer, pressure relief valve, manual fill valve) inserted (compression fittings) into its run.  At the top of the run, the feed pipe is bent through 90-degrees, with another non-return valve, before coupling to the boiler.  The overall run is probably close to 2.5 metres and is clipped in 6-places.

I now need to replace one of the inline components, and it looks like I will need to disassemble from the boiler backwards to get enough play in the pipework to remove the component.

Is this just a 'fact of life/suck it up' situation, or is there any coupling or technique that I can use when I re-assemble to make life easier in the future - something like a sliding coupling along the lines of a trombone slide maybe?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you trying to figure out how to remove the plumbing from the wall? Do you need to know how to separate the joints in the plumbing? I'm not sure where you're actually stuck. With copper pipe, the easiest thing is to just cut out the leaking(?) part and replace it with new bits of copper.

Comment: I need to replace the PRV but can’t open the pipe enough to slip the valve out of the pipe run.  I can slice the pipe, but I needed to know what couplings were available to ‘repair’ the cut pipe.  It seems I was looking for a Moody Coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They make various *repair couplings* that slide over the pipe. Some are made to solder, some have pressure-rated rubber gaskets. There are probably additional types out there too. All require a gap in the pipe.

To replace an inline component, you would cut the pipe directly upstream or downstream of the component in question, replace your component, then refit using a repair coupling:

solder type (repair, or no-stop, coupling):

[image]

rubber gasket type (moody coupling):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jimmy - this was what I was hoping for